# Can pulse widths on output pins be specified when using the RaspberryPi Gpio library?

Tags: gpiozero

According to the [AngularServo](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_output.html#gpiozero.AngularServo) documentation in the Gpiozero, one can set an `angle` for a servo (which of course in fact sets a pulse-width), or a `value` (where 0 is one end of a range and and 1 is the other, but again, in fact it's setting a pulse-width).

The [Servo](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_output.html#servo) base class for `AngularServo` does the same, abstracting from actual pulse-widths and only allowing you to set a nominal value.

I need to be able to set actual pulse-widths - is this possible, using Gpiozero?

I do it with the Python interface from pigpio, but would rather use Gpiozero.

Comment: What range of pulse widths?

Comment: You must be the joan of pigpio fame. Thank you, I love using pigpio, it's the most accurate way I've found of controlling servos from a Pi. Using Gpiozero as an interface to pigpiod will allow me to mock the interface for development. In answer to your question, I'd like to have the full 500-2500 µS range available in the pigpiod.

Comment: Can't you make 0.0 to 1.0 map to 500 to 2500 using the Servo class itself?

Comment: E.g. s=Servo(5, min_pulse_width=0.5/1000.0, max_pulse_width=2.5/1000.0) gives s.min() of 500 and s.max() of 2500.

Comment: I guess I could, but it would introduce an unwanted level of abstraction, as it's partly for educational purposes. I use `numpy.polyfit()` to produce a polynomial function that maps desired angles to pulse-widths (to account for non-linearity in and differences between motors) and it's desirable in this case for users to work with the concept of actual pulse-width values.

Comment: Ah, I'm afraid that is beyond my gpiozero knowledge.